# Database design accounts vs customer accounts

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key, user-accounts

Hello Stack Overflowers,

I'm redesigning a system for an ordering group.
We have a hundred or so companies (ordering accounts) that order from us. 
And maybe 40 of those companies also have online stores (admin accounts) with us.

An online store has a customer list of users that belong to their store, and the admin account lets them create and manage customers and customer orders.

- So the customer shops, and when finished the order goes to the company.
- The company verifies the order (combines orders to save shipping if they want) and then send it(/part of it) to us or fill it(/part of it) from their inventory.
- We pack their order at our warehouse and ship it to the address on the order.
- And we invoice the company.
- The company then settles payment with their customer. (we never bill a customer directly)

Hopefully that wasn't too convoluted...

So again, we never bill a 'customer' directly. But in our current system, we store all accounts (ordering, admin, AND customers) in the same way.

While considering the redesign, I've questioned if this is the most logical approach. And I was thinking of storing our billable accounts (ordering and admin) in an accounts table and customers in a separate customers table.

The way I was thinking of setting this up was, our accounts have an accountID XXXXX, while users have a similar userID YYYYY, but are identified by a composite key of the two (XXXXX-YYYYY)

So company A's first customer is AAAAA-000001 and company B's BBBBB-00001. This seems fine when I think about things like customer orders being billed to their parent company, and displaying all of a companies customers, etc.

But is it a bad idea to have a customer table where customers non-unique customerIDs, even if that isn't the Primary Key?

I know I could make it work, but is it suboptimal when doing something like a customer_address table that relates a customerID and an addressID? Wouldn't it then need to use an accountID + customerID right?

Originally I was thinking they would all be accounts, and the account number would just be structured that way AAAAA-00000 being the admin account, AAAAA-00001 being customer 1, and so one.

But that brings me back to, should our accounts table treat our clients/billable accounts and their customers the same?

Sorry if this question is kind of all over the place. I think that demonstrates how unsure I am of how it should all be structured...

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When building your database, you should bear in mind that what you think the requirements are right now WILL change, so how can you best cope for extensibility. Given your broad requirements you should aim to normalise everything from the start, what I can see is that you have 3 different types of "person" in your database, customers, admin and companies. I would build all of these into a single table and have a different table for "permissions", that was any customer can become a merchant etc. Keep addresses & account in separate tables and link to your primary customerId using JOINs

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
I initially did want to keep all of these together. I planned to have an Accounts table that holds all of the account info (address, registration date, status[frozen/active], etc.) and then include a Users table which held the online profiles (username, password, user type/permission, parent account). 
I will look to eliminate the multiple types of 'people' in the system. 
Thank you for the advice :)